# How do I make a specific Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

so im using excel to track my hours that i work at my job

i have it set up like this:

Columns B through G are label in this order:

```
Date  Start  Lunch out  Lunch in  home  total hrs worked
```

Column G calculate the amount of time i worked for every day, so it does a total for jan 1, a nother total for jan 2, etc.

the equation i use is =(D-C)+(F-E)  it subtracts my beginning time from when i go to lunch, and adds it to the difference between when i leave to go home and when i come back from lunch

however i dont always go to lunch and i dont want to replace the existing equation all the time..

so heres what i need..

(this is gonna be written out as how it should work.. not what the equation needs to say?)

```
IF
  Columns D and E are not blank
Then (D-C)+(F-E)

Else (this is if columns D and E are blank)
  F-C
```

Remember, Column C is when i start my shift, D is when i clock out for lunch, E is when i come back from lunch, and F is when I clock out for the day and end my shift.  and column G is the total hours i worked for that day (has the formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate the Lunch seperately and subtract that from the total:

```
=(F2-C2)-(E2-D2)
```

That way if the Lunch is blank it will subtract `0` from the total.

[image]

Comment: doesnt work...  adds a bunch of ####    if i replace your cells with numbers, its this:  (0:00-8:00)-(17:00-0:00)  = -25:00

Comment: resizing doesnt do anything

Comment: @JaredLima - You cannot have a negative time in excel. Use MIN or MAX to force a zero instead of a negative time.